# Access md-sidenav-layout object in Component (typescript file)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using md-sidenav in my application.
md-sidenav will be assigned with an object using following syntax:

```
<md-sidenav #start
```

so here "start" will be holding all variables/methods of md-sidenav and we can do various operation like start.close(), start.toggle() etc.

In case we want to do these operation through .ts file, how we can do it. How we can get "start " object in .ts file.

I've created the plunker for the same.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q2dEhOA9dzDzBlLaxmYT?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@ViewChild()` to get a reference to the component instance from a template variable:

```ts
  class MyComponent {
    @ViewChild('start') sideNav;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      // only set when ngAfterViewInit is called (not for example in the constructor)
      console.log(this.sideNav);
    }
  }
```